# Using Arraylist, Linked Hashmaps and Lists in GWT

Tags: java, list, gwt, arraylist, linkedhashmap

So GWT creats Javascript for every object and I've once heard that you should be carefull while using List for example because it is so generic and since GWT doesn't know runtime it creates classes for every kind of functionality even though you might not need it. Does this applay to ArrayList and Linked Hasmaps aswell? What should I keep in mind while using those and how can I reduce unnecessarily created code with GWT. Thank you for your help and time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This advice applies to RPC client-server communication, where GWT has to be ready to serialize all possible implementations of List or Map interfaces if a specific implementation (e.g. ArrayList) is not explicitly set.

Consider moving away from RPC and use RequestBuilder instead.

Comment: But as with any performance advice, measure and *then* cut, especially when it comes to keeping code readable and flexible. I routinely use `List`/`Map` etc in RPC code, and refining those rarely changes compile size by more than around 1%.